# How do I change an items color by clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to programming and I would like to change an items color when it is clicked to a series of colors.  I believe this could be done through CSS, javascript, or JQuery.  Which would be most efficient?

Comment: What code have you tried? Do you think that we'll doing everything for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  All I know is Dreamweaver and HTML.  I would like to create a button that changes colors to a series of colors(ex. white, red, blue, orange, black, then back to white).  If you could point me in the right direction for which programming to learn, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example, all elements that contain the class `colorable` when clicked will have another class `red` added, which changes the color of the text.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USd5m/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="colorable">Color me in</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    color:red;
}
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery)**

```
$('.colorable').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: +1 for keeping things separate, i see so many people using `.css` to color, etc instead of using css made classes

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  This was very helpful for getting a started.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have random colors, you can do the following:

**HTML**

`<div id="button">Button</div>`

**CSS**

`div {
  user-select: none;
}`

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', changeColor, false);

function changeColor() {
    this.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tryzor/HLFuC/)

Comment: Thankyou for your response.  This helps me what I need to learn.  I honestly, really appreciate it!